# Optimized conversion from Milliseconds to hours:minutes:seconds:mseconds digits?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, fpga

what are your suggestions to optimize the conversion from milliseconds `msecsOut` to 9 digits alias `iX: 8H 7H 6M 5M 4S 3S 2MS 1MS 0MS` assuming the loop is a given constraint, modulo might be suboptimal, so far i have: 
(we are programming with systemc on an Spartan-3 FPGA Family from XILINX)

```
int msecsOut = 1234123412;
// iX: 8H 7H 6M 5M 4S 3S 2MS 1MS 0MS
for (int i = 8; i >= 0; --i) {
    int digitOut = -1;
    if (i == 8) {
        digitOut = msecsOut / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 10);
        msecsOut = msecsOut % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 10);
    } else if (i == 7) {
        digitOut = msecsOut / (1000 * 60 * 60);
        msecsOut = msecsOut % (1000 * 60 * 60);
    }  else if (i == 6) {
        digitOut = msecsOut / (1000 * 60 * 10);
        msecsOut = msecsOut % (1000 * 60 * 10);
    }  else if (i == 5) {
        digitOut = msecsOut / (1000 * 60);
        msecsOut = msecsOut % (1000 * 60);
    }  else if (i == 4) {
        digitOut = msecsOut / (1000 * 10);
        msecsOut = msecsOut % (1000 * 10);
    }  else if (i == 3) {
        digitOut = msecsOut / (1000);
        msecsOut = msecsOut % (1000);
    }   else if (i == 2) {
        digitOut = msecsOut / (100);
        msecsOut = msecsOut % (100);
    }   else if (i == 1) {
        digitOut = msecsOut / (10);
        msecsOut = msecsOut % (10);
    }   else if (i == 0) {
        digitOut = msecsOut / (1);
    }
    cout << digitOut << " ";//debug only
}
cout<<endl;//debug only
```

Comment: The very first thing I would do is get rid of the divide. I have never worked with systemC thus I don't know if you can synthesize the / operator, but I bet that it would be very, very expensive in gates.

Comment: @Oldfart If the C compiler even slightly optimizing, they wont have any divisions: https://godbolt.org/g/HxUo2h

Comment: *"assuming the loop is a given constraint"* :(

Comment: why "assuming the loop is a given constraint" ?

Comment: a) this code is not **C**, so please do not tag that. b) you're using [loop-switch sequence here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence), which is a known antipattern. Don't. c) you don't need any ifs even...

Comment: There is no point in optimizing this code.  What you are going to *next* with that string is many orders of magnitude slower.  Not limited to cout.  I don't know if this toolset is spartan enough to not have a profiler, but you really, really need one to make correct decisions.  Just use another one to get the feel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get rid of testing `i` (which make your loop useless) by using arrays

```
int msecsOut = 1234123412;
const int factors[] = {
      1000 * 60 * 60 * 10,
      1000 * 60 * 60,
      1000 * 60 * 10,
      1000 * 60,
      1000,
      100,
      10
};
const char* symbols[] = {"H", "H", "M", "M", "S", "S", "MS", "MS"};
// iX: 8H 7H 6M 5M 4S 3S 2MS 1MS 0MS
for (int i = 0; i != sizeof(factors) / sizeof(*factors); ++i) {
    const int digitOut = msecsOut / factors[i];
    msecsOut = msecsOut % factors[i];
    std::cout << digitOut << symbols[i] << " ";
}
std::cout << msecsOut << "MS" << std::endl;
```

Comment: This is still rather inefficient for synthesis. DIV and MOD are very expensive. There are a few ways to do this in a area efficient way: 1. Iterative subtractor/adder. But this will not be very fast. 2. Change the DIV and MOD operations to 32 cycle implementations. But I guess the big question is:  Why do user interface converstions in a FPGA at all?

Comment: I expect compiler uses something like [std::div](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div) to do the calculation only once by iteration. and as state in comment `std::cout` would probably be the bottleneck here.